# Lyrics to Jake Bugg song 'Swept Away"

Tags: lyrics, rock, folk

I have seen several different transcriptions of the lyrics to this Jake Bugg song. And I was wondering if anybody had seen a physical copy of the lyrics like sometimes come in the case when you by a CD?
here's the link to the song:
https://youtu.be/aqfJLWlBkTc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested lyrics most likely don't exist in the requested format because this song as been released as the B-side of [*Kentucky*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jake-Bugg-Kentucky-/master/547270) 7" vinyl single. It seems it hasn't been released in CD.

[image: Jake Bugg's Kentucky]

7" discs are generally packaged in a simple sleeve that don't have much information so you won't find the lyrics on it. Personally, I've never seen a 7" sleeve with the lyrics on it.